# Bootsrap Begineer - change width of div with different screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a beginner to Bootstrap. I am trying to accomplish the following:

> To make a div that is 2 columns wide on medium and large viewports and 12 columns on extra small viewports.

I understand that bootstrap works in rows and columns(12) and that the columns have breakpoints at which they 'break' and stack as and how applied when the screen size changes. I am thus not sure how to change the width of a div as above.

Can this be done just by using Bootstrap?

They way I think this could be implemented is using javascript to get the screen size(pixels width) and then changing the width value of the div. What could be the approach? Any leads or suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add more classes according to the viewport width:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Item1</div>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Item2</div>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Item3</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Item4</div>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Item5</div>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Item6</div>
</div>
```

The above gives you an output of 4 columns for larger viewports, 3 for medium and 2 for smaller.

Extra small devices Phones (<768px) Small devices Tablets (≥768px) Medium devices Desktops (≥992px) Large devices Desktops (≥1200px)

- Extra small devices Phones = col-xs-n
- Small devices Tablets = col-sm-n
- Medium devices Desktops = col-md-n
- Large devices Desktops = col-lg-n

if you want 2 columns side by side at smaller viewports, you'll need to add them all in the same row:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Item1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Item2</div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Item3</div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Item4</div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Item5</div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">Item6</div>
</div>
```

This will give you the following output at smaller viewports

```
Item 1 | Item 2
Item 3 | Item 4
Item 5 | Item 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this, like so:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2"></div>
```

It's that easy. At the `md` breakpoint (970px) and above, that `div` will occupy 2 columns; prior to that it will occupy 12, but you can change the `col-xs-12` to any number you'd like.

The bootstrap grid system is easy to get the hang of and you don't need javascript to use it. [Read about it here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need js for that bootstrap grid system will suffice.
You should consult these docs to understand grid system in details--

[w3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp)

**example**

```css
.col-lg-2, .col-md-2, .col-xs-12
{
background-color: blue; height:500px;
}
```

```html
<html>


<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

         
           </head>
<body >
  

  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-12">
    
  </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
  </body>  

</html>
```